# Custom Keyboard for Listview

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

Im currently trying to add a custom keyboard to a list view which is dynamically populated by an ArrayAdapter.

My View Hierarchy looks like this: One Activity, which has a top bar (self made, as LinearLayout), below a FrameLayout which will contain one of 5 Fragments, and (optionally) a bottom bar below (probably as LinearLayout as well.)

My problem is where to put the keyboard view in xml, since i believe that, when i put it in the activity.xml, it is hidden behind the list view. Adding it to the list view fragment is also not possible, since "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView".

Thats the code i want to add (to make it clear, everything works in the sample app i created where there is only one activity)

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
   android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:visibility="gone" 
/>
```

Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_top">
    <!-- MY TOP BAR ELEMENTS HERE

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment">
    <!-- SPACE FOR FRAGMENT HERE -->
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout>
   <!-- SPACE FOR BOTTOM BAR HERE -->
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/feuchterechner_fragment"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
>
```

Like mentioned above, ListView is populated via ArrayAdapter. Question: Where do i have to put the keyboardView xml?

Thanks in advance!